# Viewing related value in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a nested form, the goal is to display a value of the related table record.  But the following fails

```
   <%= f.fields_for :product_units do |g| %>
      <%= g.label :product_unit, unit.name %>
```

as `undefined local variable or method 'unit'`  What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

To use the nested fields_for (f.fields_for), your model object must be setup correctly, which you haven't shown here.

E.g.: If the relation was a @product and many @product_units:

product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_units, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :units, through: :product_units
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :units #if you want to update it
end
```

product_unit.rb:

```
class ProductUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

unit.rb:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :product_units
  has_many :product_units, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then your nested form could look like this (if it's `has_one` use the singular `f.field_for`:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :product_units do |g| %>
    <%= g.fields_for :units do |u| %>
      <%= u.label :name, "Product Unit Name:" %>
      <%= u.text_field :name %> #if you want a text_field to edit it
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also if a unit doesn't exist in this form, you may need to add logic in your controller to build it first before having it display here.

Alternatively if `@product.unit` already exists for every association, you could just call that in the view if you need to display the unit label and not have it editable.

**General Comment:**

When you post errors please post the class details of your error message since `undefined method 'unit'` ***`for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder>`*** is actually *very different* from `undefined method 'unit'` ***`for nil:NilClass`***  This latter part of the message is usually more important when debugging since it tells you information about the object you're working with.

Comment: Yes,  it is a formBuilder error `for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000...>`  The model was defined   `has_many :product_units, dependent: :destroy  has_many :units, through: :product_units`.  ProductUnit also `belongs_to :product  belongs_to :unit`  The set-up does work as I can change the values to the database.  It is only the labelling that fails with the formBuilder error; the related `unit.name` value is only meant to be shown...

Comment: I've updated my answer for you.  In your original question there is no indication that ```unit``` is defined so naturally```unit.name``` is not going to work.  Depending on the original instance variable you could just call ```@product.unit.name unless @product.unit.blank?``` if you just want to show the association if it exists.